# I want to know if i am banned from entering USA for life

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, international-travel

In 2007,when i was a student from Nigeria, unknowingly to me a friend used someones credit card to pay for conference for me. I was then refused,ever since then i have always been refused a USA visa.
I became a naturalised British citizen last year 2019,i applied for authorisation online for visa waiver (ESTA),i was turned down.They told me i can apply for USA visa.I then applied with my British passport,i was refused again.
Yesterday, i applied for authorisation again on ESTA ,i was turned down.
pls i want to know if i am permanently banned from travelling to USA? As the offence committed is over 13yrs now.pls does USA never forgive?
Thank you in anticipation for your response
John.

Comment: What was the basis for denial of your visa? Was it INA 214(b)?

Comment: they gave no reason for refusal. they only asked me what happened in 2007.i told the interviewer that i was ignorant.they finally refused me

Comment: they should give you some notice that you were denied, and that should cite some section of law

Comment: its INA214(b). they gave me a similar refusal letter given to everyone.no law was cited

Comment: INA 214(b) is failure to overcome immigrant intent. It is a generic reason to deny most types of nonimmigrant visas. It is not a ban.

Comment: general refusal letter.could i have been banned for life from entering usa?

Comment: its been 13yrs the offence was committed .i dont know what to do?

Comment: Again, nothing indicates that you have a ban, but just because you don't have a ban doesn't mean you will be able to get a visa.

Comment: pls i am confused, what can i do?

Comment: pls how can one know he or she is banned?

Comment: I have never seen any process by which you can determine if you're banned. The only sure diagnosis occurs if you apply for a visa, and the visa is issued — then it is clear that you're not banned. If you apply for a visa and the visa is refused, however, the refusal notice may or may not disclose whether the visa was refused because you're banned, or for some other reason.

Comment: Why do you want to visit the USA?

Comment: i have a burial of a relative later this month

Comment: pls what can i do now ?